# grails autocommit firing update queries when the position of elements is changed in the list

Tags: grails, arraylist, autocommit

I have scenario where i need to move an object to the begining of the array list.

Right now i have something like this

```
List a = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5, obj6, obj7]
```

now to move obj4 to the begining of the list
i am removing it from the list like this

```
a.remove(obj4)
a.add(obj4)
```

and then reversing the collection

```
Collections.reverse(a);
```

when i am doing this,  grails is automatically firing update query for some of the objects

another way  which i have tried is 
i created a new list and then added elements like this

```
def b = []
b.add(obj4)

a.each{
b.add(it);
}
```

but in this case multiple update queries are getting fired, i am not at all touching  the objects.

Please help me debug this

Comment: what are the queries that are fired, can you provide a sample

Comment: thanks for replying ankur, i am trying to replicate this scenario on a sample app, will post back soon

Comment: I don't think your post described what the problem actually is

Comment: Alright, i didn't have lot of code to explain the complete scenario, that's why i tried to describe the specific part of it, i am still not sure why re ordering a list of objects fetched from database was firing an update query on the objects. i am not concerned about the down vote, but you could have read my answer or perhaps asked for some more explanation like ankur did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright i did lot of head banging and finally found a workaround for this, somehow the version(which grails provides by default) was getting updated and that's why it was firing update query, disabling the grails versioning solved the problem for me, hope that helps someone